# Swapping Characters inside an array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I'm looking to make a series of flashing lights and I want them to appear on the same line.

Something like this

```
O * O * O * O * O * O *

        Title
O * O * O * O * O * O *
```

I want these characters to swap positions to make it look like lights that are flashing

```
char Lights[10] = { 'O','*','O','*','O','*','O','*','O','*'};
for (int x = 0; x >= 9; x++)
{
    cout << Lights[x];
    if (x % 2 = 1)
    {
        Lights[x] = 'O';
    }
    else
    {
        Lights[x] = '*';
    }
}
```

This is what I Tried and the main problem is how to get it to keep printing and looping over and over on the same line. I also get an error with my for loop saying "initial condition dos not satisfy test, loop body not executed"
And for my x in the first if statement it says "exprssion must be of modifiable value"

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Ive made the array and have it printing just the characters without any swapping

Comment: How to do that depends on your terminal and platform.

Comment: Try swapping them and show us the code and we'll help you through the errors.

Comment: Standard C++ console output doesn't support "swapping" characters onscreen.  You need to use platform-specific console APIs for that, or a wrapper library like ncurses.

Comment: ISO C does not support what you are asking for. However, most platforms offer such capabilities as platform-specific extensions. Therefore, your question can only be answered if you specify which platform (i.e. operating system) your question applies to. On Windows, the answer to the question will be very different than on Linux..

Comment: I've done some research and I believe I need a pause or sleep to have some time between swaps, I also don't want to use system CLS because I will have other things printed on the screen so maybe something just to replace those two lines?

Comment: `if (x % 2 = 1)` Are you sure you meant `=`?

Comment: Ahh you're right, thank you (also I'm on windows)

Comment: @Hostyle27: If you want your question to apply to the Windows platform, then you should specify that in the question itself (by editing the question). Also, you should add the "windows" tag to the question.

Comment: @Hostyle27: You are probably looking for [`SetConsoleCursorPosition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecursorposition). You can also use [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences), but I am not sure if these are supported by earlier versions of Windows. You may require Windows 10 with a recent patch. I am sure that `SetConsoleCursorPosition` is also supported by earlier versions of Windows.

Comment: @Hostyle27: An alternative way to create a flashing effect would maybe be to use several [Console Screen Buffers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-screen-buffers) and to swap the buffers using [`SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoleactivescreenbuffer). However, I would recommend that you first try to use the other methods mentioned above, as they are probably easier to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well given your example

```cpp
 char Array[10] = {O,*,O,*,O,*,O,*,O,*}
```

You could just print them once from beginning once from the end.

```cpp
void printForward(char arr[10]) {
    for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--) {
        std::cout << arr[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
void printBack(char arr[10]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::cout << arr[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
void printLight(char arr[]) {

}
int main() {
    char arr[10] = { 'O','*','O','*','O','*','O','*','O','*' };


    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        if (i % 2) printForward(arr);
        else printBack(arr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You could also add clear console screen, for example on windows it would look like this

```cpp
#include<iostream>
void printForward(char arr[10]) {
    for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--) {
        std::cout << arr[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
void printBack(char arr[10]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::cout << arr[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
void printLight(char arr[]) {

}
int main() {
    char arr[10] = { 'O','*','O','*','O','*','O','*','O','*' };


    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (i % 2) printForward(arr);
        else printBack(arr);
        system("cls"); //this will clear, but its unsafe and you should look
        //for better ways to clear screen on windows
        //for unix like systems you can print "\033c"
    }

    return 0;
}

That would be the way to print your desired output
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that it is possible for multiple lines, but for one, this is the way in linux:

```
while(true)
{
    std::cout<<"\rO * O * O * O * O *"<< std::flush;
    sleep(1);
    std::cout<<"\r* O * O * O * O * O"<< std::flush;
    sleep(1);
}
```